# Effect of setting seeds on an algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm

I am writing an R code where, I am using set.seed() function in the whole program to generate the data and then using it in a function , ultimately plotting the function and then using optim to get the minima. But now the issue is the graphs of the function changes if I change the seed value and sometimes doesn't even produce a concave graph but an exponential graph. 
I am not able to understand why this is happening and how I can fix it. If anyone can provide me with any reference to read in this subject or any suggestions as to what can be done, that will be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are interested how a random number generator works, check out [this 
video on Super Mario World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q15yNrJHOak)

Answer (score 1):

`set.seed()` configures the random number generator to start from that seed. This may be a bit more complicated, depending on the precise implementation, but the effects are always the same: The sequence of numbers will be identical.

This is useful in a number of applications where you want some randomness, but you want to get the same result if you re-run the code. Say for example you need to randomly sample your data, but since you are debugging, it's useful if you get the same sample so that the bugs don't disappear on you.

Also if you want other people to replicate the results, you simply pick some random number as the seed and tell them that you used that seed. Anything in the algorithm based on random numbers will behave the same because you are both using the same sequence of numbers.

For your graph problem you need to share some code so that people understand what you are doing. It's very hard to guess what went wrong. At the outset it seems that you algorithm is very strongly influenced by the random numbers (usually not a good sign).

Comment: Hey, so here is the piece of code which i am using for function,nrow(mesh)-sum((mesh$zone %in% inf.zones)*pnorm(x,mean = mesh$z.expected, sd = sqrt(mesh$z.var)),
    (!(mesh$zone %in% inf.zones))*(1-pnorm(x,mean = mesh$z.expected,sd = sqrt(mesh$z.var))))

Answer (score 1):

In simple, if you set a seed, and extract a random number, the random number will be always the same. If you not set a seed, every time you choose a number the number will be different. The seed permit you to replicate your experiment.

Comment: So my function is basically about taking pnorm in one region and taking 1-pnorm in the complement of the area. I cannot share the whole code at this moment cause it is kind of in two different files but here I share the formula for the R code:- nrow(mesh)-sum((mesh$zone %in% inf.zones)*pnorm(x,mean = mesh$z.expected, sd = sqrt(mesh$z.var)),
    (!(mesh$zone %in% inf.zones))*(1-pnorm(x,mean = mesh$z.expected,sd = sqrt(mesh$z.var))))

Comment: I don't think the problem is in pnorm. pnorm gives the distribution function. There is nothing random. The pnorm depends only on the data.

Comment: Then what do you think could be the reason for bizarre graphs? Could it be related to use of optim?

Comment: you need to explain better your problem.

Comment: Code is working fine. But once I start plotting the graph for pnorm I am getting exponentially decaying graph but theoretically it should decay and then increase so as to give a concave shape. Theoretically it is correct but in code it isn't behaving in such way also if I change seed value , graphs are getting affected which also says that it means the code is not robust and probably I cannot use for any dataset. So I want to sort out :- 1)Drastic effect of seed;2)minima not appearing in the graph. But first I want to sort problem 1